# Python - Adding channel to category

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a channel that'll be created in a category but the things I've tried haven't worked

The code is pretty big so I won't be showing everything, just down to adding the channel

```
@client.command()
@has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def warn(ctx, member:discord.Member, *, reason=None):
 arg=reason
 author=ctx.author
 guild=ctx.message.guild
 overwritee = discord.PermissionOverwrite()
 overwrite = discord.PermissionOverwrite()
 channel = get(guild.text_channels, name='warn-logs')
 category = get(guild.category_channels, name='Multi-Logs')
 mrole = get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Multi-Galaxy")

 if category is None:
  category = await guild.create_category_channel("Multi-Logs")
  overwritee.read_messages = False
  overwritee.read_message_history = False
  overwritee.send_messages = False
  overwrite.read_messages = True
  overwrite.read_message_history = True
  overwrite.send_messages = True
  await channel.set_permissions(guild.default_role, overwrite=overwritee)
  await channel.set_permissions(mrole, overwrite=overwrite)
 if channel is None:
  channel = await guild.create_text_channel('warn-logs')
  overwritee.read_messages = False
  overwritee.read_message_history = False
  overwritee.send_messages = False
  overwrite.read_messages = True
  overwrite.read_message_history = True
  overwrite.send_messages = True
  await channel.set_permissions(guild.default_role, overwrite=overwritee)
  await channel.set_permissions(mrole, overwrite=overwrite)
```

It just creates the category & the channel apart from each other, so the channel isn't in the category

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass in a `category` in [`create_text_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_text_channel):

```
if channel is None:
    channel = await guild.create_text_channel('warn-logs', category=category)
    #                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    #                                  keyword-argument––––^^^^^^^^
    #                                        your-variable––––––––––^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: and how'd I get the category, the things I've tried haven't worked for me, (but it wouln't surprise me if I've gotten it wrong :| )

Comment: @DrJakaboii You already have the category variable. (Even if it's None, you're assigning it with a new channel.) If things somehow didn't workout, feel free to [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56508041/edit) your question with the specific problems and/or errors you're facing.