# Create channel in Category discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I know, I know it's here - [Python - Adding channel to category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56508041/python-adding-channel-to-category)

But I'm getting an Error...I'm using Python 3.9 with discord.py's version 1.5.0 I think...So here is my command:

```
@client.command()
async def create ( s, arg: str ):
   guild = s.message.guild
   c = 'FORUM' 
   channel = await guild.create_text_channel ( arg, category = c )
```

Even tough the category exists, I get an error saying:

```
Ignoring exception in command create:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User1\Gifts.py", line 13, in create
channel = await guild.create_text_channel ( arg, category = c )
File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 905, in create_text_channel
data = await self._create_channel(name, overwrites, ChannelType.text, category, reason=reason, **options)
File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 823, in _create_channel
parent_id = category.id if category else None
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

What can be the problem? What do I need to do? Please give me a solution...Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The category it's not supposed to be a string, but a `CategoryChannel` instance, with `utils.get` you can get it by the name

```py
@client.command()
async def create(s, arg: str):
   guild = s.message.guild
   cat = discord.utils.get(s.guild.categories, name="FORUM")
   channel = await guild.create_text_channel(arg, category=cat)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the name of the category, but you need to pass the category itself!
You can get the category by calling:

```
c = get(guild.category_channels, name = "FORUM")
```

Source:
[How to get a category by its id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63695135/how-to-get-a-category-by-its-id)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
@client.command()
async def create(ctx, arg: str):
   channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(arg, category=discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name='FORUM'))
```